# How to change java heap in Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin, compiler-errors, xamarin.android

guys. I have a problem with java heap.
I have this error:

```
error XA5213: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing 'java.exe -Xmx1G -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.0\lib\dx.jar" --no-strict --dex --multi-dex --main-dex-list=obj\Release\multidex.keep --output=obj\Release\android\bin obj\Release\android\bin\classes "G:\Programs for development\VisualStudio2017\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.0\mono.android.jar" "G:\Programs for development\VisualStudio2017\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\android-support-multidex.jar" obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports\appodeal-2.1.7.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__applovin-7.4.0.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__appnext-2.0.3.459.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__avocarrot-3.8.2.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__chartboost-6.6.3.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__dagger-2.7.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__eventbus-2.2.1.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__facebook-4.26.0.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__flurry-ads-7.0.0.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__flurry-analytics-7.0.0.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__inmobi-6.2.3.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__ironsource-6.6.2.1.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__javax.inject-1.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__mailru-4.6.17.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__ogury-2.1.15.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__picasso-2.5.2.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__rxjava-1.2.0.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__startapp-3.6.2.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__tapjoy-11.11.0.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__unity_ads-2.1.0.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__vungle-sdk-android-5.1.0.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__yandex-metrica-2.73.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports__reference__yandex-mobileads-2.61.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\AppodealXamarinPlugin\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\FormsViewGroup\library_project_imports\formsviewgroup.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads\library_project_imports\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite\library_project_imports\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base\library_project_imports\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement\library_project_imports\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Clearcut\library_project_imports\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Drive\library_project_imports\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Games\library_project_imports\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gass\library_project_imports\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps\library_project_imports\classes.jar obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks\library_project_imports\classes.jar'
```

Afrer i change java heap space in my Android Project. And I have same when java heap space is 0.
Help, please, to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on Android project -> Android Build -> Select configuration -> Advanced -> Java heap size

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. At me, as it has appeared it has been registered _Java_Options -Хмх1g

Comment: @Rollinart Great, then please mark my answer as correct when you can :)